# Communicating between iOS application and Python Desktop application

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing a proprietary iOS application that will need to communicate wirelessly with a python program on only one desktop computer. In the past I have always set up an http server on the desktop computer with a simple protocol for receiving data from the iOS device. The python program receives this data and updates its interface. Could anyone recommend a different approach, or confirm this is a practical way to approach this architecture? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on what application/system you are trying to build.

As you said you can use a server with e.g. [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API and have your clients communicate with it using standard HTTP methods.

Alternatively, you can use `NSStream` and `CSStream` to communicate from within your `iOS` apps to a `TCP` server on your desktop machine. Keeping an open socket connection with your server will allow the server to send you a notification about the events instantly. You will need an output stream (`NSOutputStream`) and an input stream (`NSInputStream`) so you can manage outgoing and incoming communications easily and in parallel.

Some useful links:

[Introduction to Stream Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000188i)

[How To Create A Socket Based iPhone App and Server](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)

[Tutorial: Building A Simple iOS TCP Socket Based App Client And Server](http://maniacdev.com/2011/06/tutorial-building-a-simple-ios-tcp-socket-based-app-client-and-server)

Comment: Thanks! What do you believe is easier to implement? and which will allow more instantaneous communication?

Comment: It is much easier to go with implementing a RESTful server and client then implementing socket communication. You could use e.g. `RestKit` However, sockets give almost instantaneous communication.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a practical approach. Depending on the roles, either a desktop or an iOS device can be a server (i.e. there's nothing wrong with having iOS app be an HTTP server running on a non-privileged port).

Depending on the payload types and performance requirements you may want to look into something different from HTTP server. I've had positive experience building and iOS app and Python script that communicate via [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) (iOS app was a server).

From your question it's not entirely clear if the app is for internal consumption or not; if it's intended for wider audience I recommend that you adopt [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/) or similar discovery protocol to make configuration of your apps easier (basically, they will be able to "see" each other without configuration).